# Windows 10 shows 0bytes file size from Android when connected over USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, android

Recently I noticed that when I connect my Android phone to my Windows 10 PC, some file sizes are reported to be 0bytes and when I try to open those files, I get error messages.
See these screenshots: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClWNa.png) and [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR7bI.png).
This happens only with the files which are there in an external SD card inserted into my phone.
There isn't any problem when I try to open those files in my Android phone.

What is the cause of this issue and how to solve it? I cannot understand whether the problem is in the phone or in the PC. That's why I posted the question in this site.

*Please note that if my language is wrong, then please edit the question.*

Comment: Are you cable to copy those files to your PC? Can you play them if you do?

Comment: Yes, I am able to copy those files to PC, but they are still of 0bytes and not playable.